# iOS - Block messages/email notifications while driving

Tags: ios, imessage

Is it possible to block iMessage/Emails from within the app when user starts driving? Somthing similar to "Do not disturb" but triggers when vehicle starts/stops moving. As far as I know it is not possible in iOS.

I know its possible for Android devices and found many examples like  DriveSafe.ly, tXtBlocke,Textecution but haven't found that blocks messages/emails. Does anyone know any solution for this scenario?

UPDATE: Just noticed, company called cell control claims to support iPhone for such functionality. Still not clear how it works though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Even if your app is full screen and hides all OS UI, notifications will show.

Comment: Thanks leo. http://www.cellcontrol.com/where-to-buy-cellcontrol/ --> they claim to be doing this. just found out and also they havent mentioned which iOS version it supports.

Comment: @akash Looks like private API use to me. Are they safe for AppStore?

Comment: its available in appstore. any idea how possibly this could be implemented? Thanks.

Comment: @akash Can you provide a link to iTunes app?

Comment: @akash They either private API or they do not do it on iOS.

Comment: video here http://www.cellcontrol.com/driveid/ clearly shows iPhone supporting this feature.

Comment: @akash I am not sure what the feature was. Did it block slide to unlock? I saw only "Please do not use" message and driver passed the phone to another passenger.

Comment: haha. the second user tried to swipe in candy crush game. but it did not work.

Comment: From how I read it they're not actually blocking calls while driving, but recording the fact that you made/received a call while driving and "scoring" you based on that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. CellControl is only saying they locked the phone.

“We send a key-press to the phone that says, ‘press the power button,’” said Joe Breaux, chief technology officer at CellControl. “We’re turning the screen off, and then we turn it right back on to say we’ve locked the phone.”

It’s basically an Apple workaround. “Apple doesn’t offer any public APIs that would allow blocking applications,” said Breaux. (Android offers more visibility and access.)